# How do I send an email when a Google Form is submitted?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

How do I send a notification email after a form has been submitted?

I have a Google Form, I open it and I go to menu *More->Script Editor* and add a script:

```
function OnSubmit(e) {
  MailApp.sendEmail ("myemail@mydomain.com", "Form Submited: Foo feedback " + Date.now(), "Form Submited: Foo feedback");
}
```

I save the script and test it works by pressing the run button. The email gets delivered to *myemail@mydomain.com*.

Then I fill in the Google Form, but the email does not arrive in myemail@mydomain.com mailbox.

P.S.
I do not want to use "Email Notifications for Forms" plugin because it requests access to to many privileges. I do not want to use "Form Notifications" because for some reason it does not work for me (the emails do not get delivered).

Comment: Kindly try manually creating a "On form submit" trigger and attaching it to your function. Let me know if this work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found it, well hidden under

- Edit form mode
- `Responses` tab
- `...` menu button
- `Get email notifications for new responses`.

[image]

Comment: thanks, this works without requiring an add-on! Amazing

Comment: this sends only notification not the data in email. Is there other setting which sends data as email notification.

Answer (score 5):

To send an email when a form is submitted you need to copy the following script to your script editor, run `createTrigger` once and accept the necessary permissions. This function looks for the 'on form submit' triggers, and if it finds none it creates a new one. After that you can submit the form and it will send an email specified in `onFormSubmit` function

```
function createTrigger() {
  
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm(); // active form

  var formTriggers = ScriptApp.getUserTriggers(form); // form triggers

  var noTrigger = true; // assuming there is no 'onFormSubmit' trigger

  for (let t = 0; t < formTriggers.length; t++) {
    let trigger = formTriggers[t];
    if (trigger.getEventType() == ScriptApp.EventType.ON_FORM_SUBMIT) {
      noTrigger = false; // trigger exists
      break;
    }
  }

  if (noTrigger) {
    Logger.log('Creating trigger');
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit')
      .forForm(form)
      .onFormSubmit()
      .create();
  } else {
    Logger.log('OnFormSubmit trigger already exists')
  }

}

function onFormSubmit() {
  MailApp.sendEmail ('recipient@email.com', 'New form submission', 'Form submitted on ' + new Date());
}
```

Comment: As you wrote the code it will create a new trigger every time the function get called...very bad idea !  The trigger creation function must be in a separate function that runs only once. And also it would be be nice to explain your answer to make it useful.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed it it sends several emails now instead of one. Do you know how to register the trigger only once?

Comment: check if a trigger already exists using https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app  and use the result in a condition before creating a new one

Comment: @Sergeinsas thanks, done! Can you remove the -1 pls?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The easier way, now, is to use the "Notification rules..." item under "Tools".

[image]

Comment: Where can I find this menu. I don't see this menu on Google Form!

Comment: @Krunal See my answer, I just found it.