# Google Forms - confirmation Email summary

Tags: google-sheets

I created a form to collect some data. By default the responder to the form gets a PDF summary after submitting the Email. Does anybody know if it is possible to send this summary to a second Email adress I mean a copy of the summary to the form Hoster?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Cheers

Comment: This is not implemented by default. But you could try to do it with apps script using a form trigger, [`onFormSubmit()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder#onformsubmit). Are you used to [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)?

Comment: Hi Raserhin, thanks a lot. that's what I supposed. I tried a bit but have no experience with App Script. Just used VBA so far. But will Google for it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically repeating what I said in the comments there is no way to add another email address by the UI but you could try to use [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).

You can use a [`onFormSubmit()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder#onFormSubmit()), this is a [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) that executes every time a form is submitted.

You could try to look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49336231/11758896), where there is a definition of a trigger and sending a email:

```js
/**
 * This function is the one that will be executed every time the trigger is activated
 */
function respondToFormSubmit() {
   MailApp.sendEmail ("email@domain.com", "Form Submited: Foo feedback " + Date.now(), "Form Submited: Foo feedback");
}
```

The setup of the trigger:

```js
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var trigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger('respondToFormSubmit')
  .forForm(form)
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this.